# Python OPP: access from parent class to child variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want to reuse code. My Base class have a abstract method and public method. Public method require a variable that are generated in `__init__`. If I create abstract properties, there will be duplicate code.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Base(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def _load_cache(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def start(self):
        # Other tasks
        self._load_cache()

        print(self._name)  # I don't know how to deal with self._name. For me this is incorrect. PyCharm lint shows 
        # Unresolved attribute reference '_name' for class 'Base' 


class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self._cache = []

    def _load_cache(self):
        self._cache = [1, 2, 3] # load from DB


class B(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def _load_cache(self):
        self._cache = [4, 5, 6]  # load from DB

B('test').start()
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a basic issue beginning OOP programmers hit again and again and again. `Base` does **not** have `_name`. It **cannot** access something it doesn't have. If you need `_name` in `Base`, **put it there**. If it cannot be there, don't access it there. It's just the way OOP works. `self._name = name` **is** duplicate code. Put it in the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Base(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name =name

    @abstractmethod
    def _load_cache(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def start(self):
        # Other tasks
        self._load_cache()

        print(self._name)  # I don't know how to deal with self._name. For me this is incorrect. PyCharm lint shows 
        # Unresolved attribute reference '_name' for class 'Base'
```